# Sharing user profiles in two Django projects

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if it possible to create two Django website
Both work independently.
If the User signup on site A
The new contact information will be sent to site B using API automatically.

If the user adds a post on site A, site B gets its copy.

Site B is the parent of multiple sites like site A owned by users.

The users create something on their local site, and B gets a copy of the user push.

I'm looking to create a federated network of multiple social websites and a Base website for the storing of Public posts only.

Comment: I just sounds like you want to have a common backend for all sites.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I do partially agree, saying "1 backend for all origins" means you are going to share 1 database for 2 projects, but it sound bad, because the OP need only to share user info.

Comment: @Ghazi He also said that he want to share posts and "The users create something on their local site, and B gets a copy of the user push." so for me it sounds like he want to share more stuff. And this still works with my solution. You can have common part and separate part. Django Apps are nice fit for it

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to make Restful backend that will be shared among many websites.

Answer (score 1):

whenever a user create their profile/sign up, be sure that the client send a request to 2 origins (in your case 2 backends), this way, the user profile is stored in both backends

OR

figure out how to connect the same database (or part of it) to the two projects.

I suggest the first method, since it is easier to do and maintain.

Edit:

for the 2nd suggestion, the only way you can share a table (users table) between 2 db, is by copying the table to the other db, which seems ineffective.

Comment: Thanks Mate, can you visit executivesdiary com the diaries and members stories. I want to create a social network where every instance work independently.

Comment: The Diary is a tribe and it will have it's own private network.

Comment: The stories which is public data will be collected on Executivesdiary domain. Whenever a user sign up on any tribe domain n server it's diary will be created on ED. on ED every diary will have a a Tribe name attached. If two user become fellows their local networks store their data, will just work as meeting hub.

Comment: Check out my LinkedIn post for presentation.  https://www.linkedin.com/posts/muhammadnauman100_thankyou-entrepreneur-leadership-activity-6975854491849887747-SLiV?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_ios